# missing Packet tracer physical Tab

Tags: switch, router, vlan, packet-tracer, networking

[image: screeen shot of the router]

hello I am using packet tracer for a while.I use in my college computer. but recently I installed in my pc. when ever I try to add extra ports in my rouer or switch the physical tab is missing

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try select Option from menu bar, click "Preference", switch to "Hide" tab and uncheck the "Hide physical tab" box. Hope this helps.